# How to use multiple toggle switches created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, toggleswitch

I am a beginner in Frontend. I am implementing toggle switches in HTML,CSS and Vanilla Javascript.

**Structure:**

I create an HTML  with "n" number of rows depending on the data in my django database. Each row has some data like name, id, status. Status column has toggle switches for each row. I have implemented the toggle switch which works fine for one single toggle switch.

**Problem:**

When there are multiple rows, and hence, multiple toggle switches, only the first toggle switch is getting toggled not the others. When I click on other toggle switches then also the first one gets triggered.
I want all toggle switches to work separately and to detect it in my vanilla javascript.

**What I know**:

I know that we need unique id for each toggle switches but I don't know how to do that when I don't know how many rows I will have and how to detect all of them in JS code.

**Code**:

```js
var myswitch = document.querySelectorAll(".idm-switch_div .toggle");
myswitch.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var isChecked = document.querySelector(".toggle-checkbox").checked;
    localStorage.setItem("checkstate", !isChecked);
    console.log(!isChecked);
  });
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 15.32px;
  width: 30.33px;
  border: 1px solid #b8cfd9;
  border-radius: 17.5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
/* After slide changes */
.toggle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  height: 11.62px;
  width: 11.96px;
  background-color: #8566c1;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.toggle-checkbox:checked + .toggle::after {
  left: 59%;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Checkbox cheked toggle label bg color */
.toggle-checkbox:checked + .toggle {
  height: 15.32px;
  width: 30.33px;
  border-radius: 17.5px;
  background-color: #8566c1;
}

/* Checkbox vanished */
.toggle-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-checkbox:checked + .toggle::after {
  left: 59%;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Checkbox cheked toggle label bg color */
.toggle-checkbox:checked + .toggle {
  height: 15.32px;
  width: 30.33px;
  border-radius: 17.5px;
  background-color: #8566c1;
}

/* Checkbox vanished */
.toggle-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="idm-switch_div div-container">
                <input type="checkbox" id="switch" class="toggle-checkbox" />
                <label for="switch" class="toggle"> </label>
              </div>

<div class="idm-switch_div div-container">
                <input type="checkbox" id="switch" class="toggle-checkbox" />
                <label for="switch" class="toggle"> </label>
              </div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in html you can use {{forloop.counter}} in your checkbox id and label for attribute, so they can have their unique id
2. in js, you can use your original addEventListener code, because you have unique toggle switch id now, so it can recognize which one you want to toggle

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Show User List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/list.css" %}" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="grace-name">
          <img
            src="{% static 'images/arrow-left.svg' %}"
            class="idm-product-icon idm-product-icon-left"
          /><label class="idm-product_name idm-bold">GRACE </label>
          <img
            src="{% static 'images/arrow-left.svg' %}"
            class="idm-product-icon idm-product-icon-right"
          />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a class="active" href="#news">USERS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">MACHINES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">AUTHORIZED CONNECTIONS</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="idm-batch-table-container">
      <table class="idm-data-grid">
        <thead>
          <th></th>
          <th>User ID</th>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Full Name</th>
          <th>Enabled</th>
          <th class="idm-status_header">User Connections</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for user in users %} {% if not user.is_staff %}
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label class="idm-container-checkbox idm-checkmark-batch-table"
                ><input
                  type="checkbox"
                  class="yeschecked"
                  name="
                        batch-ptions" /><span
                  class="idm-checkmark idm-batch-checkmark"
                ></span
              ></label>
            </td>
            <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.fullname }}</td>
            <td>
              <div class="idm-switch_div div-container">
                <!-- give forloop.counter in input id and label for attribute -->
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="switch_{{forloop.counter}}"
                  class="toggle-checkbox"
                />
                <label for="switch_{{forloop.counter}}" class="toggle"> </label>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button class="table-connect">
                <img src="{% static 'images/Vector.png' %}"
              </button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button class="table-edit">
                <img src="{% static 'images/edit.png' %}"
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="{% static 'javascript/user.js' %}"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello @Jane. Can you tell me how to call this function in HTML given my problem that I have to add these toggle buttons in my table rows? I cannot use onclick() anywhere. How can I call your function with the number of rows in my database?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer with your updated code, I found that you use django, so maybe you can ignore my original answer with createElement() dynamically

Comment: Hello Jane. Thank you so much for your effort and answer. I used the {{ forloop.counter }} as you suggested and in my javascript that I used, I get the id from the element.parentNode.childNodes[1].id and I am able to identify which toggle switch is pressed and what is it's current value. I am accepting your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` to toggle separately . As I have used `parrentElement` so used extra `div` element outside of each switch so that it take values from separate classes when called

```js
function toggled(el) {
  var isChecked = el.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("toggle-checkbox")[0];
  if (isChecked.checked == true) {
    isChecked.checked = false;
  } else {
    isChecked.checked = true;
  }
}
```

```css
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 15.32px;
  width: 30.33px;
  border: 1px solid #b8cfd9;
  border-radius: 17.5px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}


/* After slide changes */

.toggle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  height: 11.62px;
  width: 11.96px;
  background-color: #8566c1;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.toggle-checkbox:checked+.toggle::after {
  left: 59%;
  background-color: white;
}


/* Checkbox cheked toggle label bg color */

.toggle-checkbox:checked+.toggle {
  height: 15.32px;
  width: 30.33px;
  border-radius: 17.5px;
  background-color: #8566c1;
}


/* Checkbox vanished */

.toggle-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.toggle-checkbox:checked+.toggle::after {
  left: 59%;
  background-color: white;
}


/* Checkbox cheked toggle label bg color */

.toggle-checkbox:checked+.toggle {
  height: 15.32px;
  width: 30.33px;
  border-radius: 17.5px;
  background-color: #8566c1;
}


/* Checkbox vanished */

.toggle-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="idm-switch_div div-container" onclick="toggled(this)">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch" class="toggle-checkbox" />
    <label for="switch" class="toggle"> </label>
  </div>
</div>


<div>
  <div class="idm-switch_div div-container" onclick="toggled(this)">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch" class="toggle-checkbox" />
    <label for="switch" class="toggle"> </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @daad. Can you tell why your function is logging twice on clicking one switch? Also seeing that you are using class name to identify switch, can one toggle switch be uniquely identified? Suppose i want to store the current state of one switch so that on page refresh I see the state of switch as was before(on or off)

Comment: You have to use cookies to remember the state and other things like name and other info . So whenever user comeback his data is saved unless he/she deleted the cookies .

Comment: You can use label to identify the switches  so whenever a switch is clicked call the label & print the state of its switch

Comment: In your solution, on printing the isChecked, two things are getting printed. First is the state of toggle switch and other is always true. Why is that happening?

Comment: It is because I have taken your code and didn't remove this part `localStorage.setItem("checkstate", !isChecked);
  console.log(!isChecked);` .   It is again setting checked

Comment: localstorage is just saving the state. Even after removing that line the console logs twice. Logging is showing the behavior that for some reason, the toggle switch is setting correctly but the value in "checked" state is not giving correct value.

Comment: Share a image of the result you got  and code you used . It can be due the reason of get item from 2 classes using `this`  but executing the clicked one , You can check if it is printing three times if you use 3 classes of toggle switch .

Comment: No it still prints twice even after adding 3 elements. I found out that the first value it is printing is of the current toggle switch. The second value it is printing is of the first toggle switch. Suppose A,B,C are three switches in this order. If I toggle B, the value of B will be printed first, then the value of A. I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: I have solved it using solution given by @jane. Thank you for your answer daad I appreciate it :)